# What is -inf really?

Tags: python, math, infinity

Is this just the smallest number that can be stored in 32 bits for example?

```
from math import inf
```

Comment: See [`sys.int_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.int_info) for integer sizes. `inf` is a float point numerical value not an integer — see [`math.inf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.inf).

Answer (score 4):

Floating-point numbers (real numbers as typically implemented on a computer) have special values reserved for positive and negative infinity. Rather than just being “the largest or smallest representable 32-bit numbers,” they act as though they really are infinite. For example, adding anything to positive infinity (other than negative infinity) gives positive infinity, and a similar rule holds for negative infinity.

For more on this, do a search for “IEEE-754 infinity.”

Comment: Just a note that it is not just addition, most arithmetic against `inf` results in `inf` other than those involving `-inf` then the results tend to be `nan`